# Backgrounds cut off in scrolling flexbox inner elements

Tags: css, flexbox

I am trying to get two elements to take up the full height of a scrolling flexbox parent:

- I have two divs within a scrolling flexbox parent
- This is then wrapped again with a fixed height parent
- When the content overflows the initial height the background of the two divs does not take up the full height

**The wrapper with the fixed height cannot be set to scroll**

```css
.wrapper {
  height: 200px; // Cannot be set to scroll, needs to be fixed height
}
 
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.sidebar {
  background: orange;
}

.main {
  flex: 1;
  background: grey;
}

body {
  margin: 0
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="sidebar">
      <p>Sidebar</p>
      <ul>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="main">
      <p>Main</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Weird layout and constraints you have there.

But you can add [`flex-wrap: wrap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-wrap) on `.container` to solve the problem

```css
.wrapper {
  height: 200px;
}
 
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
}

.sidebar {
  background: orange;
}

.main {
  flex: 1;
  background: grey;
}

body {
  margin: 0
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="sidebar">
      <p>Sidebar</p>
      <ul>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="main">
      <p>Main</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It is a strange layout yeah, any idea why that works? The items are clearly not wrapping.